# Unicode error when inserting into MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, character-encoding

I have a script that stores content of random web pages into mysql database ([MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html)). For some of the pages, I get:

```
...
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py",
  line 264, in literal
return self.escape(o, self.encoders)                                         
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", 
  line 202, in unicode_literal
return db.literal(u.encode(unicode_literal.charset)) 

UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character
u'\u203a' in position 172550: ordinal not in range(256)
```

When I used [sqlite3](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html), I had no problems with that.

I tried this one, without success:

```
CREATE DATABASE the_base CHARACTER SET utf8
```

Question:
How to encode/decode the data correctly so it is stored in the DB without *any problems ever*?

P.S.  Character encoding under python is a never ending story...

**Solved**

Added encoding to `connect` method:

```
MySQLdb.connect( ... charset='utf8', use_unicode=True )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't store random unicode in an encoding that only has ~256 possible entries (ie. latin-1).  Change the encoding in your database to e.g. utf-8 and you should be good to go.

Comment: I just tried `CREATE DATABASE the_base CHARACTER SET utf8` but still the same error

Comment: Make sure you have `charset='utf-8'` in your connection parameters (especially if your database and server have different encodings).

Comment: works! actually, it needs to be `utf8` , `utf-8` throws an error